# OpenGL ES apps appear to run MUCH FASTER when profiling in Instruments

Tags: ios, opengl-es, instruments

I'm scared to ask this question because it doesn't include specifics and doesn't have any code samples, but that's because I've encountered it on three entirely different apps that I've worked on in the past few weeks, and I'm thinking specific code might just cloud the issue.

Scoured the web and found no reference to the phenomenon I'm encountering, so I'm just going to throw this out there and hope someone else has seen the same thing:

The 'problem' is that all the iOS OpenGL apps I've built, to a man, run MUCH FASTER when I'm profiling them in Instruments than when they're running standalone. As in, a frame rate roughly twice as fast (jumping from, eg, 30fps to 60fps). This is both measured with a code-timing loop and from watching the apps run. Instruments appears to be doing something magical.

This is on a device, not the iOS simulator.

If I profile my OpenGL apps and upload to a device — specifically, iPad 3 running iOS 5.1 — via Instruments, the frame rate is just flat-out much, much faster than running standalone. There appears to be no frame skipping or shennanigans like that. It simply does the same computation at around twice the speed.

Although I'm not including any code samples, just assume I'm doing the normal stuff. OpenGL ES 2.0, with VBOs and VAOs. Multithreading some computationally intensive code areas with dispatch queues/blocks. Nothing exotic or crazy.

I'd just like to know if anyone has experienced anything vaguely similar. If not, I'll just head back to my burrow and continue stabbing myself in the leg with a fork.

Comment: Are you sure it's running the same build? By default, "run" uses the Debug build (typically `-O0`) and "profile" uses the Release build (typically `-Os`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could be that when you profile, a release build is used (by default) instead of a debug build when you just hit run.

Comment: You're absolutely right furnoboy. I'd not even considered that Instruments would use a release build; if anything I'd assumed it would be slower from all its data monitoring. Thank you.

Comment: I had a similar problem in a macOS Swift app in Xcode 10.1 loading data for about 46,000 football players (heavily multithreaded using dispatch queues and operation queues, with many async network fetches) and the code runs WAY faster when time profiling, OR with an Archive build. After some analysis, I discovered that Xcode is throttling my network connection when running from Xcode (this is on Wifi, Debug or Release). From Xcode, it limits to about 14K/sec, but when running though Instruments, or in an Archive build, I get 150K-180K sec. So if using heavy network code, watch out for this.

Comment: Note on my previous comment: network throttling seems to be fixed in Xcode 10.2 + macOS 10.14.X. Not sure which one fixed it, but I'm getting full bandwidth when running from Xcode now.